# Странное значение переменной name в глобальном контексте

Tags: javascript

Заметил странность:

```js
var name = 0;
name = name || 4;
console.log(name);
console.log(typeof name);
```

Не понимаю почему выводится `0` и `string`, если при сравнении оба числа и `0` вроде как `false`. По идее, должно выводиться `4` и `Number`.

Но если написать такую функцию:

```js
function new1() {
    var name = 0;
    name = name || 4;
    console.log(name); 
    console.log(typeof name); 
}
new1();
```

То выводит всё верно: `4` и `Number`.

Comment: если написать 0||4 - возвращает 4. потому что 0 - false?

Comment: Очень похоже на баг браузера

Comment: @AlexKrass, это не баг, это фича :-)

Comment: Кажется, ответ принять надо.

Answer (score 15):

Одна из неочевидных особенностей. у объекта window, есть [свойство `name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

При выполнении данного кода в глобальном контексте, вместо переменной используется это свойство, так как при попытке определить переменную в глобальном контексте, идет попытка добавления одноименного поля в объект window.

Так как в этом объекте уже есть свойство *name* для него просто вызывается сеттер, и ему записывается указанное значение.

Далее в условии уже проверяется не число 0, а строка "0", которая не эквивалент false.

```js
console.log(window.name)
var name = 10;
console.log(window.name, name, window.name === name);
```

Для обхода можно так же воспользоваться объявлением переменной с помощью оператора [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), в этом случае не происходит добавления в глобальный объект

```js
let name = 0;
name = name || 4;
console.log(name);
console.log(typeof name);
```

Comment: Что самое удивительное, этот сеттер любое присваимое значение переводит в тип String. Это отличает его от обычного свойства объекта.

Comment: в ES6 лечится через `let` .... `let name = 666;` .... name выведет 666, а `window.name` выведет строку по дефолту

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, опоздал :-) уже дополнил примером :-)

Comment: @Grundy 6 секунд - считай одновременно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но я вперед :P