# Prompt и возвращаемое значение

Tags: javascript

Вызов `prompt` возвращает то, что ввёл посетитель – строку или специальное значение `null`, если ввод отменён.
При этом `typeof null // object`.
Однако работа следующего  кода мне не понятна:

```
var name = prompt('Введите логин');
console.log(name);
console.log(typeof name);

var name2 = prompt('Введите логин2');
console.log(name2);
console.log(typeof name2);
```

Выше приведенный код запускает модальное окно, жмешь отмена, результат в консоле

```
    console.log(name);  // null
    console.log(typeof name); // string
```

Далее запускается второй prompt, жмешь отмена, результат в консоле:

```
console.log(name2); // null
console.log(typeof name2); // object
```

Почему при идентичном коде возвращаются различные значения?

Нажми оба раза "отмена"

```js
var name = prompt('Введите логин');
console.log(name);
console.log(typeof name);

var name2 = prompt('Введите логин2');
console.log(name2);
console.log(typeof name2);
```

Comment: код одинаковый - он не может при одних и тех же действиях давать разные результаты. Следовательно, либо ты делаешь разные действия, либо ты пробуешь разный код. В обоих случая ты должен отредактировать вопрос, добавив в него недостающую информацию

Comment: @Grundy ну как же информация полна. В консоль вставляешь код, он запускает первый prompt жмешь отмена, результат выводится в консоль. Запускается второй prompt жмешь отмена, результат в консоль.

Comment: Вот так и надо было писать. Сейчас это выглядит так: жмешь _Esc или кнопку "отмена"_ и получаешь разный результат. Вот я нажал два раза Esc - у меня все правильно :-)

Comment: @Grundy и все же, я думаю ты понял суть вопроса, есть какие предположения о происходящем?

Comment: [prompt(message, default)](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#dom-window-prompt) по идее ответ тут: во-первых, проблема в том, что ты _сразу_ второй раз вызываешь, во-вторых, почему-то возвращается _строка "null"_

Comment: @Grundy, вот и я о том...почему-то возвращается строка "null" ... хотя должен object null иначе if(name) даст true... непонятное поведение...

Comment: @pepel_xD поменяйте имя переменной с `name` на `name1`. Это фокус такой.

Comment: А вообще лучше всегда указывать default value.

Comment: @emre проблема ни разу не в `prompt`.

Comment: @Regent, да :-) не обратил внимания, у нас даже вопрос такой есть про это [Странное значение переменной в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/553258/186999)

Comment: @Grundy то бишь зря я начал писать ответ... Всё время забываю проверить - а нет ли уже такого на русском SO.

Comment: @Regent, Ну если ты не успел обновить страницу, ответ можешь и дописать :-) тут просто у того вопроса заголовок не очень, надо бы как-то подправить, а то и не найдешь так, если не знаешь, что есть

Comment: Всем спасибо за направление на путь истинный :), как говориться век  живи, век учись.

Comment: @Grundy так если уже есть и найден ответ нормальный - зачем заново его писать?) Поправил только тот вопрос немного, чтобы он больше смахивал на каноничный.