# Написать текст при фокусировке javascript

Tags: javascript

Я подключаю свой js в html:

```
<input id="name" name="input-name" class="input-search" type="text">
```

Функция из script.js которая должна сработать при фокусе на поле с id = name, как я понимаю

```
name.onfocus = function() {
    name.value = 'Ivanov'
}
```

есть в форме поле для ввода:

```
<input id="name" name="input-name" class="input-search" type="text">
```

Но я что-то делаю не так, я гуглил и не совсем понял как с этим разобраться.

Comment: По коду, вроде бы , все норм. Нужно проверить подключение скрипта.

Comment: `name` это [плохое имя для переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553264/186999) и лучше выбирать более конкретное имя. В крайнем случае использовать `getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя `script` подключен в `head`

```
<head>
   <!-- script подключен не правильно  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>LAB3</title>
</head>
```

А должен быть подключен тут перед закрывающим `body`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Так как когда страница грузиться парсер начинает читать код, сверху вниз...  А у тебя `input` к этому времени не загрузился...

Ну и как ниже сказано реализовать функции, даже если бы скрипт был подключен правильно, все ровно не работал бы...

Функцию же надо запустить...

```js
function funName(elem) {
  elem.value = 'Ivanov'
}
```

```html
<input id="name" name="input-name" class="input-search" type="text" onfocus="funName(this)">
```

Вариант автора с испралениями

`name` ни-где не инициализирована...

```js
//name переменно не существует,  ее надо объявить

let name = document.querySelector('#name');


name.onfocus = function() {
  name.value = 'Ivanov'
}
```

```html
<input id="name" name="input-name" class="input-search" type="text">
```

Но я бы Реализовал так так:

```js
document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.value = 'Ivanov'
})
```

```html
<input id="name" name="input-name" class="input-search" type="text">
```

Comment: разве он может видеть this.value?

Comment: у меня это не работает

Comment: Странно, что тут в примере почему то работает....  Магия...

Comment: Щас изменю второй пример, может понятнее будет

Comment: Это же не `JQ`, надо захватить элемент, а потом вешать на нее обработчик

Comment: 1 вариант работает, но мне хотелось бы это решить 2 вариантом

Comment: ну тут то работает...второй

Comment: Изменил ответ почитай\