# Почему не равны переменые?

Tags: javascript

```js
var BlockName = document.body.className;
var Name = document.body.className;
BlockName == name;
```

Когда выполняю возвращает:

```js
false
```

Comment: Вопрос вызван опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже на банальную опечатку: не `BlockName == name;`, a `BlockName == Name;`. Переменные в JS чувствительны к регистру, `name` и `Name` - разные переменные(просто переменная `name` в данном случае берется из `window.name`, [и вот почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553258/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-name-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/553264#553264), поэтому результат - `false`)

Comment: _просто переменная name не определена в данном случае_ - не то, чтобы [совсем не определена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553264/186999) :-D

Comment: @Grundy :O
Спасибо :) Поправлю ответ

Comment: @Grundy Кстати, теоретически, ТС может пытаться выполнить этот код не в браузере, там переменная все же будет не определена :)

Comment: может :) и даже в браузере не всегда это будет свойство глобального объекта :)