# В чем различия var, let, const для объекта window?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Вроде бы много читал про `var, let, const`, в чем различия я вроде понимал, но не тут то было.

Но обнаружил, что для глобального объекта ***window***  `let и const` не объявлены.

```js
var varName = 'varName';
const constName = 'constName';
let letName = 'letName';

console.log('varName  ', window.varName);
console.log('constName  ', window.constName);
console.log('letName  ', window.letName);
```

с  чего вдруг такое поведение? Как я понимаю, все три переменные в области видимости объекта `window`

Вот пример в котором я столкнулся с проблемой, получается, что `var` важен и нужен и не умер

в этом все работает

```js
var name = 'windowViniamin';

function hello() {
  console.log('hello', this.name);
}
const person = {
  name: 'Viniamin',
  sayHello: hello
}

person.sayHello();
hello();
```

а в этом нет  (вместо этого `10dbb4dd-bf80-4d80-8ee2-a6a4954a029d` должно быть пусто, у меня в браузере так)

```js
const name = 'windowViniamin';

function hello() {
  console.log('hello', this.name);
}
const person = {
  name: 'Viniamin',
  sayHello: hello
}

person.sayHello();
hello();
```

Comment: ответ есть https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776236/6104996  но надо перевести))

Comment: Они и не должны попадать в свойства глобального объекта, по определению. Перед тем как задать вопрос, ты не читал статьи на MDN о `let` и `const`? _«Директива let объявляет переменную **с блочной областью видимости** ...»_, _«Константы (const) подчиняются **области видимости уровня блока** так же, как переменные, объявленные с использованием ключевого слова let.»_

Comment: @yar85, _директива let объявляет переменную с блочной областью видимости_ - в вопросе речь про глобальную область, формально там все три переменных в одной области

Comment: @Grundy, а, действительно... верное замечание.

Answer (score 4):

В соответствии со [спецификацией](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-global-environment-records)

> Глобальный *environment record* логически это один environment record, однако, включающий в себя [declarative environment record](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records) и [object environment record](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object-environment-records). При этом *object environment record* в качестве базового объекта использует [глобальный объект](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-global-object).
> *Object environment record* входящий в глобальный *environment record* содержит в себе все привязки встроенных глобальных значений. А так же привязки добавленный с помощью *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, *AsyncFunctionDeclaration*, *AsyncGeneratorDeclaration*, или *VariableStatement* содержащихся в глобальном коде. **Привязки для всех остальных ECMAScript определений, описанных в глобальном коде, добавляются в *declarative environment record* входящий в глобальный *environment record*.**

Небольшое пояснение:

- **declarative** environment record хранит привязки во встроенной структуре данных. К этой структуре невозможно обратиться напрямую.
- **object** environment record в качестве структуры данных использует обычный javascript объект. Каждое свойство в этом объекте соответствует привязке и наоборот. В глобальном environment все привязывается к глобальному объекту.

Как указано в цитате выше, только *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, *AsyncFunctionDeclaration*, *AsyncGeneratorDeclaration*, или *VariableStatement* добавляются в *object environment record*, т.е. только такие привязки становятся свойствами глобального объекта.

Все остальные объявления (let или const) добавляются в *declarative environment record*, который не связан с глобальным объектом.

---

<sub>Вольный перевод ответа [@FelixKling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776236/2881286)</sub>

Comment: @Viniamin так никто не будет делать, потому что не имеет смысла. Либо его правильно вызывать с переданным контекстом а-ля `hello.call(person);` либо если это просто функция - то передавать аргументом что-то. Иначе это вообще UB

Comment: @Viniamin в легаси коде лучше его не трогать, в новом коде лучше никогда не использовать

Comment: @Viniamin, имя `name` в глобальном скопе [_особенное_](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553264/186999)